# Zend Navigation (Container) - removePage() is not Recursive

Tags: php, zend-framework, recursion, zend-navigation

`Zend_Navigation` extends `Zend_Navigation_Container`.  The `findOneBy()`, `findAllBy()`, and `findBy()` functions all search for pages recursively, but `removePage()` does not.  This means that `$navigation->removePage($navigation->findOneBy('id', 'page_10'));` will work ONLY if `page_10` is a root-level navigation node.  Has anyone else encountered this and found a work-around?

---

I have found my own solutions and accepted one of them as how I have implemented it.  I will select a solution from someone else if it's better than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend `Zend_Navigation` and `Zend_Navigation_Container` to recursively remove pages.

Create `My_Navigation_Container` that extends `Zend_Navigation_Container`:

```
abstract class My_Navigation_Container extends Zend_Navigation_Container
{
    /**
     * Remove page(s) matching $property == $value
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @param mixed $value
     * @param bool $all
     * @return My_Navigation_Container
     */
    public function removeBy($property, $value, $all = false)
    {
        $pages = array();

        if ($all) {
            $pages = $this->findAllBy($property, $value);
        } else {
            if ($page = $this->findOneBy($property, $value)) {
                $pages[] = $page;
            }
        }

        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $this->removePageRecursive($page);
        }

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * Recursively removes the given page from the container
     *
     * @param Zend_Navigation_Page $page
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function removePageRecursive(Zend_Navigation_Page $page)
    {
        if ($this->removePage($page)) {
            return true;
        }

        $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($this, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
        foreach ($iterator as $pageContainer) {
            if ($pageContainer->removePage($page)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Make a copy of `Zend_Navigation` that extends `My_Navigation_Container`:

```
class My_Navigation extends My_Navigation_Container
{
    /**
     * Creates a new navigation container
     *
     * @param array|Zend_Config $pages    [optional] pages to add
     * @throws Zend_Navigation_Exception  if $pages is invalid
     */
    public function __construct($pages = null)
    {
        if (is_array($pages) || $pages instanceof Zend_Config) {
            $this->addPages($pages);
        } elseif (null !== $pages) {
            throw new Zend_Navigation_Exception('Invalid argument: $pages must be an array, an instance of Zend_Config, or null');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the parent, and then remove the child. This requires knowledge of the parent's attributes:

```
$navigation->findOneBy('id', 'parent_id')
        ->removePage($navigation->findOneBy('id', 'child_id'));
```